# Async DrillDown functionality in Highcharts with Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, drilldown

I am working in Angular 4 application. In this application we need to show different charts. I am using highcharts for showing different charts.

I want to Implement drilldown charts. I want to bind the drilldown series on user click.

Below is the code I am using:

I have added drilldown event as below in my chart object:

```
chart: {
      type: 'column',
      events: {
           drilldown: (e,e2) =>{
           if (!e.seriesOptions) {
            var chart = e.target.options.chart;
            chart.showLoading('Loading');
            var dataArr = [1, 2];
            chart.setTitle({
              text: 'Quarter wise Revenue Report'
            });
            var data = {
              name: e.point.name,
              data: dataArr
            }
            this.service.customDelay()
              .subscribe(heroes => {
                chart.hideLoading();
                chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, data);
              });            
          }
    }
}
```

In the above code service is the service object of my service and customDelay is the method which is for adding some delay for testing purpose.

I am getting below error in above code:

> chart.showLoading is not a function

To resolve this I have update the above drilldown function after removing arrow function as:

```
drilldown:function (e){
 if (!e.seriesOptions) {
        var chart = e.target.options.chart;
        chart.showLoading('Loading');
        var dataArr = [1, 2];
        chart.setTitle({
          text: 'Quarter wise Revenue Report'
        });
        var data = {
          name: e.point.name,
          data: dataArr
        }
        this.service.customDelay()
          .subscribe(heroes => {
            chart.hideLoading();
            chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, data);
          });            
      }
}
```

In this case chart.showLoading and other function are working of chart but this.service becomes undefined.

Comment: `this.service.customDelay()` is not part of highcharts so it is undefined

Comment: Use old school approach:   let self = this    and then use self.service

Comment: customDely is defined in my service

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk seems to have the point. Just create the `service` variable and assign `this` to it right before the chart constructor is used. Then simply use `service.customDelay` in your `drilldown` event.

Comment: I have resolved this as:

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue, As below code is working in my case:

```
events: {
      drilldown: (e) => {
        console.log('drill-down');
        if (!e.seriesOptions) {
          var chart = e.target;
          if (chart.options.lang.drillUpText !== ChartStyle.drillUpBackBtnText)
            chart.options.lang.drillUpText = ChartStyle.drillUpBackBtnText;
          if (this.drilldownsData[e.point.name]) {
            chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, this.drilldownsData[e.point.name]);
          }
          else {
            chart.showLoading('');
            let months = CommonUtilityService.getPreviousNMonthYearString(3);
            this.chartDataService.getTenetMeasureDataMonthWise(e.point.tenetId, this.selectedTeam.TeamId, months)
              .subscribe(response => {
                let responseData = <IChartData>JSON.parse(response['_body']);
                let data = CommonUtilityService.createDrillDownData(responseData, "Rating", ChartStyle.ChartXAxisStyle, ChartStyle.MaxBarWidth);
                this.drilldownsData[e.point.name] = data;
                chart.hideLoading();
                chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, data);
              });
          }

        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
chart.showLoading('Loading');
```

To:

```
chart.ref.showLoading('Loading');
```